# Limit the length of the output of "rss" command in conky

Tags: conky

I'm running conky with desktop RSS. Is it possible to limit the max length of its title?

I have something like this in my config:

`${rss XXX 30 item_title 4}${goto 600}${rss YYY 30 item_title 4}`

So it would be crucial that the first rss title won't exceed 600 in length, is it possible to limit that?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs I don't see a way to do it using `rss`.

- http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

Obviously with Conky you could write your own parser and use the `execi`. You could use `curl` or perhaps use this script instead, [How to add an RSS feed to Conky/conky-rss.sh](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_add_an_RSS_feed_to_Conky/conky-rss.sh).

*excerpt conky-rss.sh*

```
# RSS Feed Display Script by Hellf[i]re v0.1
#
# This script is designed for most any RSS Feed. As some feeds may not be
# completely compliant, it may need a bit of tweaking
#
# This script depends on curl.
# Gentoo: emerge -av net-misc/curl
# Debian: apt-get install curl
# Homepage: http://curl.haxx.se/
#
# Usage:
# .conkyrc: ${execi [time] /path/to/script/conky-rss.sh}
#
# Usage Example
# ${execi 300 /home/youruser/scripts/conky-rss.sh}

#RSS Setup
URI=http://www.foxnews.com/xmlfeed/rss/0,4313,1,00.rss #URI of RSS Feed
LINES=6 #Number of headlines

#Environment Setup
EXEC="/usr/bin/curl -s" #Path to curl

#Work Start
$EXEC $URI | grep title |\
sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N' |\
sed -e 's/[ \t]*//' |\
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/ \1/' |\
sed -e 's/\.//' |\
sed -e 's/\"//' |\
sed -e 's/\"//' |\
head -n $(($LINES + 2)) |\
tail -n $(($LINES))
```